# How do I set ctrl+e to be "end of line"?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have recently gotten a system 76 gazelle lap top with ubuntu 12.10.  So far
a I very happy except with one feature.  I am use to

ctrl+e   for end of line.

ctrl+a   for beginning of line.

These work on the bash shell command, but not on other applications such as,
sublime text 2 gedit, and in a search window on firefox.  (In these ctrl-a
seems to "select all" and "ctrl-e" does no seem to do anything).  Since this
occurs in several applications I assume that some global setting is involved.
(What thats the place of these is "End" and "home" on
the keypad.)

I use sublime text 2 on anther machine and having these differing key bindings is
making me a bit nuts.

I know "set -o vi" and "set -o emacs" set the keyboard bindings in the bash shell 
and am assuming that there is on a line or two of code that is read upon startup that
will fix this.  Can anyone offer advice?

And I apologize if this has been answered before, but was not able to find the
answer online.

Best wishes,
Ralph Howard

Answer (score 2):

With gnome-tweaks you can set, via *Keyboard & Mouse*, the "Emacs Input".

This changes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to "begin-of-line" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to "end-of-line" (and other stuff too).

Answer (score 1):

Changing CTRL-A conflicts with pretty much every application out there, because it's the standard select all keyboard shortcut, so I don't think that is possible with any GUI applications.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will see if I can just to the change inside of sublime text.